# How to find the shortest distance between $z^2 -xy = 1$ and the origin using Lagrange multiplier?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

My task is this:

Find the points on the surface $z^2 -xy = 1$ with the shortest distance to the origin.

My work so far:

Let $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ and $g(x,y,z)=z^2 -xy -1$ then we have to solve:

$\nabla f = \lambda\nabla g \to \begin{pmatrix}2x\\2y\\2z\end{pmatrix} = \lambda\begin{pmatrix}-y\\-x\\2z \end{pmatrix}$, if $z = 0$ then I get the points $(\pm \sqrt{2}, \pm \sqrt{2}, 0)$ which are not even on the graph. If $z \neq 0$ then $\lambda = 1 \to x= -y/2, y = -x/2$. Substituting this into our constraint we get:

$z = \pm\sqrt{1- y^2/2}$ or $z = \pm \sqrt{1 -x^2/2}$. Im stuck here and need some help. Any hints or better approach would be appriciated!

Comment: As the objective function and the constraint are quadratic, the Lagrangian equations form a linear system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z=0$ you have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2x&=-\lambda y\\
2y&=-\lambda x\\
xy&=-1
\end{aligned}
$$
and the first two of these imply that $\lambda^2=4$ and that $x=y$ or $x=-y$ and the first of these is incompatible with $x$ and $y$ being real and satisfying the third equation. So you are left with $x=-y$ and $xy=-1$...

If $z \ne 0$ we have $\lambda=1$ and so:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2x&=- y\\
2y&=- x\\
\end{aligned}
$$
which force $x=y=0$ and so to satisy the constraint $z^2=1$ ...

... and to cut a long story short the case $z\ne 0$ gives the points of minimum distance from the origin, and that distance is $1$

Comment: Could you explain how you got $xy = 1$? If $z = 0$ shouldn't $xy = -1$? The rest looks very good, after plotting it now it sure looks clear to me that the points closest is in fact $(0,0,\pm 1)$.

Comment: @Thomas - typos, fixed now ... I hope

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrangian equations are

$$\begin{cases}\begin{align}2x&=-\lambda y\\2y&=-\lambda x\\2z&=2\lambda z\\z^2&=xy+1\end{align}\end{cases}$$
A systematic approach is by noting that the first three form a parameteric linear system with determinant

$$\left|\begin{matrix}2&\lambda&0\\\lambda&2&0\\0&0&\lambda-1\end{matrix}\right|=(\lambda-1)(4-\lambda^2).$$

For a non-trival solution (the trivial one doesn't satisfy the fourth equation), we discuss the three roots,

- $\lambda=1\implies x=y=0, z$ indeterminate; then $z^2=1$ and $d^2=1$.
- $\lambda=\pm2\implies x\pm y=0, z=0$; then $0=\mp x^2+1$ and $d^2=2$ or there is no solution.